# access control of another page asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a label in abc.aspx, say 'label1'. I want to assign a value to 'label1' from another page xyz.ashx. How can i do this?

Comment: You can make a request to the handler, and then set the value from your abc.aspx.

Comment: Why would you want to?  I suspect there is a much simpler way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Pls give some more details. What I understood is that u need to assign a value of a textbox ? U can use some ajax for doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this doesn't make sense.

When your second page is executing, the first page is gone. It simply no longer exists. There is no label for you to assign to.

Even if you could assign to the label, the previous request is over. The HTML (without the change) has already been sent to the user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think u pls try this
call `getValue`in document.ready

```
getValue = function() {
                $.post('../ax/a.ashx?val=1'
                            ,
                            {
                                  spc: data // pass some data
                            }
                            , function(data) {                                    
                                    document.getElementById("<%=textBox1.ClientID %>").value = data;
                   });
            }
```

Comment: Please include the fact that his "other page" has become this handler.